# Allow ftp access but disable terminal access on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shell, ftp

I have 2 users to whom i want to disable terminal access, but still keep ftp access.How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention, I'm using vsftpd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proftpd will not allow nologin shell, just disable the non-shelled users in SSH by allowing only trusted shell users:

In `sshd_config` :

```
AllowUsers toto john chuck morice
```

Comment: Altough this was not the kind of solution I was after, since I wanted to do something with FTP server, but it did provide a solution.

Answer (score 5):

As I just stumbled upon this post:

Setting the login shell to `/sbin/nologin` using e.g. quanta's comment might result in some login problems with the message `(530 Login incorrect)`. This can be the result of this shell not being registered with the system. Just add it to `/etc/shells` and the problem solves.

(Same for /bin/false ...)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable shell with:

```
usermod -s /sbin/nologin <ftp_user>
```

or use virtual users.

Answer (score 1):

Due to

**RequireValidShell** directive in proftpd which is by default ON
one needs to either add /bin/false to /etc/shells or turn
RequireValidShell to off and then

```
usermod -s /bin/false <ftp_user>
```

reference : [proftpd RequireValidShell directive man page](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_RequireValidShell.html)